# In Ag grid Angular how to capitalize First letter of columnDefs

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have been looking into alternate CSS solutions to capitalize the first letter of headerName of columnDefs.

So here is my solution:-

```
Object.keys(row).forEach(field => {
   columnDef.push({
      field: field,
      headerName: this.customHeader(field)
   })
});

private customHeader(val: string): string {
   return val.charAt(0).UpperCase() + val.slice(1);
}
```

So is it possible to achieve capitalization [First letter capital and rest would be small letter] using CSS styling only for Header names in the grid.

My approach for this was:-

```
columnDef.push({
      field: field,
      headerName: this.customHeader(field),
      cellStyle: { color: red, textTransform: 'capitalize' }
   })
```

By adding cellStyle CSS styling didn't work.
Two observations done here is:-

1. color red got applied to all the cells except header of the grid.
2. textTranform is not even applied

Please help!
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `cellStyle` applies the style to cell(data) and not headers.

Comment: use headerclass property in `columnDefs` the CSS class name supplied to `headerClass` will get applied to the header
  e.g.  `{ headerName: 'Athlete Details', headerClass: 'my-css-class'}`

Answer (score 1):

Ag-Grid has a feature to capitalise the field name using the field value.  So if you do not pass anything as headerName Ag-Grid will automatically take your field name and capitalise the first character.

Therefore one solution is not to provide any value for headerName just provide field parameter.

Also check [this link for more elaborate details](https://dev.to/ag-grid/ag-grid-tip-headernames-hgm)